# SQL - Search for cases where sum(amount) column across 2 tables are not equal

Tags: sql

Table1 has one row per id, table 2 has one row per id where entrytype = 0 and multiple rows per id where entrytype = 1.

I run the following queries:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM table1 where id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'

select sum(amount) from table2 where entrytype = 0 and id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'

select sum(amount) from table2 where entrytype = 1 and id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'
```

And get the following results:

```
7689.12

7689.12

7689.119999
```

Now, I want to search both tables' `sum(amount)` for cases where table1 `sum(amount) <> table2 sum(amount)` for a particular id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement correctly, you could join each of your queries on their common `id` field, and then simply select those `id` values for which the summation is not equal across the three subqueries, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.id, a.s1, b.s2, c.s3
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s1
        FROM table1 
        GROUP BY id
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s2
        FROM table2
        WHERE entrytype = 0
        GROUP BY id
    ) b ON a.id = b.id
)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s3
    FROM table2
    WHERE entrytype = 1
    GROUP BY id
) c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE NOT (a.s1 = b.s2 AND a.s1 = c.s3)
```

You didn't specify a DBMS, so I've included the extra parentheses required by MS Access, just in case.

By using `INNER JOINs`, I've also assumed that you're only interested in records which exist in all three subqueries; if one of the subqueries is the master, join the other two subqueries using `LEFT JOINs` so that all records in the master are returned.

---

Including the two additional columns mentioned in the subsequent comments -

```
SELECT a.id, a.s1, b.s2, c.s3, a.s1 - b.s2 AS s4, a.s1 - c.s3 AS s5
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s1
        FROM table1 
        GROUP BY id
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s2
        FROM table2
        WHERE entrytype = 0
        GROUP BY id
    ) b ON a.id = b.id
)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS s3
    FROM table2
    WHERE entrytype = 1
    GROUP BY id
) c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE NOT (a.s1 = b.s2 AND a.s1 = c.s3)
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I expected. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, is there a way to add an additional 2 columns: s4 = a.s1 - b.s2, and s5 = a.s1 - c.s3?
so the data would look like:
ID s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016 7689.12 7689.12 7689.119999 0 0.000001

Comment: @ChalenSchoyer I have updated my answer above - you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for a particular id, you can use `cross join` to bring them together:

```
select t1.amount, t2_0.amount, t2_1.amount
from (SELECT sum(amount) as amount FROM table1 where id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'
     ) t1 cross join
     (select sum(amount) as amount from table2 where entrytype = 0 and id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'
     ) t2_0 cross join
     (select sum(amount) as amount from table2 where entrytype = 1 and id = 'AUS|License|Maintenance|Aug_2016'
     ) t2_1;
```